# Using fixtures to load data for manual testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, frontend, fixtures

I'm using RSpec + FactoryGirl for automated testing.

For front-end development, i need some "real" data, to work with.

How can i use standard rails fixtures, to load such data, as i need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just create fixtures under your `test/fixtures` directory as you would when using Rails' built-in testing. Then you can load them into your development DB with

```
rake db:fixtures:load
```